# Improving speed of template class without using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am building a template engine with the concept that i learnt from http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1433&lngWId=8 in my web application.

I realized that it is not a very efficient way of doing template engine due to the usuage of file_get_contents. It will cost loading times.

Anyone here can offer any experts on how i can not use file_get_contents?

Comment: As opposed to what? If you want to replace values in the string, you'll *have* to read the file into memory somehow. `file_get_contents` is as good as any other function at doing that.

Comment: when i tested it, i used a load time script, it seems that sometimes file_get_content used a few secs to load the entire html code into string. (Yes, i want to replace values in string)

Comment: Then I'd first ask to verify your testing procedure. Reading a file from disk sure is comparatively slow, but `file_get_contents` should not be *that* slow.

Comment: Why does PHP need a template engine? PHP is a template engine.

Comment: I used to program in your style, but the loading time for about 20 files was very low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My magic crystal ball tells me that you are loading the templates through urls.

```
file_get_contents("http://...");
```

Stop doing that. It's slow.

Use local filesystem paths.

```
file_get_contents("../templates/foo.html");
```

Comment: +1 This is the best explanation for taking seconds to load the file.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I tried using filesyems and it gave this error. [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in C:\wamp\www\s\classes\Template.class.php on line 22

Comment: it seems that  file_get_contents on the local file will actually get you the code for the file, not the PHP-processed result of running that file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the advices. I redesigned the template engine without using file_get_contents. It seems that using include is better for local system.